# Tuple rearrangment Python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
check = open(a, 'r')
line =check.readlines()
for items in line:
    breakup= items.split()
    length = (len(breakup)-1)
    number[0], salary[1], position[2], oname[3:length], first[-1] = breakup
    data.append(tuple([first, oname, number, position, salary]))
```

This chunk of code reads from a text file that has generic information e.g:

```
15674 24000 Manager Gregory the 1st John
```

I am trying to use the for loop to append the information to data in the order I have asked it so the above information would come out as:

```
('John', 'Gregory the 1st', 15674, 'Manager', 24000)
```

The reason I have oname slicing from position 3 to the penultimate position is oname could be any number of names however first name will always be one item so I am 100% sure that I can call it from position[-1]

The issue I have is it isn't working. The code will read the file correctly and break it up correctly however I cannot get it to rearrange properly.

Comment: Unless `number`, `salary`, etc. are lists, the assignment won't work. I am sure that you don't understand tuple assignment here.

Comment: The items fed in are in lists and I assign it into a list of tuples for me to print out and modify later on. A silly requirement for my work if you ask me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to split your line differently, then assign the parts *without* index and slice assignments:

```
number, salary, position, rest = items.split(None, 3)
oname, first = rest.rsplit(None, 1)
data.append((first, oname, number, position, salary))
```

This retains the spaces in the `oname` field. The first call splits only 3 times, giving you the first three fields, and a remainder. The remainder in `rest` is then split *from the right*, once, to give you `oname` and `first`.

Demo:

```
>>> items = '15674 24000 Manager Gregory the 1st John\n'
>>> number, salary, position, rest = items.split(None, 3)
>>> oname, first = rest.rsplit(None, 1)
>>> first, oname, number, position, salary
('John', 'Gregory the 1st', '15674', 'Manager', '24000')
```

Comment: That seems a lot cleaner way to do it and works like a dream. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about this? It splits each line into tokens, and then puts each token in its proper place. You were doing things backwards - you should index the list of tokens, not the variables you want to assign them to. This assumes that "manager" will contain no spaces - otherwise, manager and name would be ambiguous.

```
data = []
with open(a,r) as f:
    for lines in f:
        toks = lines.split()
        data.append((toks[-1], toks[3:-1], int(toks[0]), toks[2], int(toks[1])))
```

This will make oname a list of words, rather than a string with spaces in it. If you want it to be a string, just replace `toks[3:-1]` with `" ".join(toks[3:-1])`.

Comment: This makes `oname` a list; I suspect the OP wants to have a string with spaces still in place.